# SQLalchemy return tuples when querying all()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, tuples

I'm trying to get a list of integers, for this query:

```
session.query(C.ex_id).filter(c.foo==foo).all()
```

I get a list of tuples instead of list of integers. I don't want to iterate over the list I get, I want to get it form the query itself.

What can I do?

Comment: all will return tuple only, to get single integer you either iterate or get single id with .one()

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you want, but one work around is:

```
some_list = map(lambda (x,):x, session.query(C.ex_id).filter(c.foo==foo).all())
```

Comment: Please do not use that; map+lambda is extremely unpythonic; there are list comprehensions for that.